# loopy belief propagation in Bayesian network

Tags: bayesian-networks

I want to use **loopy belief propagation** in **Bayesian network** for **big data**. There are several software.Which one is better for my purpose? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only software package that I am sure implements loopy belief propagation is [SamIam](http://reasoning.cs.ucla.edu/samiam/). You can find the tutorial on how to use loopy belief propagation in SamIam [here](http://reasoning.cs.ucla.edu/samiam/iframe/videos.html%5C). Just click on "Tutorial: Belief propagation".

SamIam is written in Java, so you can run it on any platform. It is free for non-commercial use.

The other two packages you might want to check out are [UnBBayes](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unbbayes/) (open source) and [GeNie](https://dslpitt.org/genie/) (closed source).